# Oracle idle connections lost

Tags: oracle

I have a problem with an Oracle 11g instance. 
Every connection that has been idle for about 20 minutes are lost.
I get the following error

```
ORA-03135: connection lost contact
```

I did the following actions to get rid of it:

- Changed the value os the `IDLE_TIME` in DEFAULT profile to `UNLIMITED`
- Checked the TIMEOUT parametes in `sqlnet.ora`. There are no one setted
- Checked the TIMEOUT parametes in `listener.ora`. There are no one setted

This problem only happens remotely.

What more I can do?

Thanks.

Comment: If it only happens remotely it's unlikely to be Oracle's fault. You need to talk to your sysadmins; it can be the server dropping idle connections or maybe some special firewall/proxy settings.

Comment: It will be a firewall problem, as @Ben said.

Comment: How can i check if firewall is killing the sessions?

Answer (score 3):

Add the option `ENABLE=BROKEN` into tnsnames.ora. This will enforce sending TCP Keepalive packets over TCP connection. These keepalives are not sent by Oracle client but by OS Kernel directly.

Then you must configure your TCP stack. Set TCP sending interval to value lower than 20 minutes.

Most probably you have a FW on the path and this FW drops tracking information for every in-active TCP connection.